# Can't resolve 'create-react-class'

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I've those files, I'm trying to add hobbies from Data.js and  print all the hobbies in

way  to my App.js,  using those files, 
but I keep getting this error that `create-react-class` isn't found,

anyone knows how to fix it ?

App.js

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import Projects from './Components/Projects';
    import './App.css';
    import Data from './Data.js';
    import Profile from './Components/profile';
    import Hobbies from './Components/hobbies';

    class App extends Component {

      render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">

<Profile name={this.props.profileData.name}imgUrl={this.props.profileData.imgURL} />
<Hobbies hobbyList={this.props.profileData.hobbyList}/>
  <h3 > My Hobbies : </h3>
     </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

Hobbies.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');

var Hobbies = createReactClass({
render: function(){
    var hobbies = this.props.hobbyList.map(function(hobby, index){
        return (<li key={index}>{hobby}</li>);
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <h5>My hobbies:</h5>
            <ul>
                {hobbies}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
  }
});

export default Hobbies;
```

Profile.js

```
import React from 'react';

var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');
var Profile = createReactClass({
render: function(){
    return (
        <div>
            <h3>{this.props.name}</h3>
            <img src={this.props.imgUrl} />
        </div>
    )
  }
});

export default Profile
```

Data.js

```
var data={

name:'it's me',
imgURL: 'me',
hobboyList:
[
  'diving',
  'soccer',
  'sleep'
]

}
export default data
```

Comment: Did you install `create-react-class`? Why are you using it anyway? Why not use the "current" way of defining React components?

Comment: I did install it, how do u use the current way ?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: I wasn't able to do it, it keep giving me error

Answer (score -1):

Run the command and install the npm package create-react-class using:
npm install create-react-class

then again build the react project and start your server.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).